# Visual Studio Community 2019 does not find my project template

Tags: visual-studio

I have created some project templates for Visual Studio. I put them in the correct template folder from Visual Studio, but I can't find it in the "Start"-Dialog. I tried the search, but it is not listed.
There are two other templates, which are listed correctly. 
The only thing I found is this, but didn't help me either:
[Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/408221/vs-2019-new-project-dialog-missing-custom-template.html)

Has someone an idea how I can get this solved?

Comment: After I updated VS my template was available. Then I created another template and this is also not found... Should I now wait till the next update?

Comment: I am having the same experience.  I export a template from Visual Studio using the Export Template Wizard and allow it to automatically import.  This appears to work correctly and the template ends up in the correct location.  However, when I go to create a new project using the new project dialog, the template is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Create a new project" window you need to select "All Languages", "All Platforms" & "All Project Types" from the 3 comboboxes to have it appear in the list.  (If the Clear All link is there, that will work too).